# Parse Categorizing Users

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

So I am working on a social application and I only want to show posts by users that go to the same school.

Here is the code I have for the method to do that:

PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];

```
PFQuery *retrieveData = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Posts"];
[retrieveData whereKey:user[@"school"] equalTo:@"Millersville"];
[retrieveData findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {


    home = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:objects];

    [mainTableView reloadData];


}];
```

I used Millersville as just a test school and when I run the application the table is blank and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

```
// reload UIKit objects in main

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [mainTableView reloadData];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure you can query Parse like this:

```
[retrieveData whereKey:user[@"school"] equalTo:@"Millersville"];
```

key argument should be a string in my opinion. You could try querying for user objects and then query Posts with the set of user objects.

Answer (score 0):

I researched more into the PFQuery call and it acutally has another option where you can do a query with a predicate which allowed me to filter the posts i needed to.